# Woocomerce: How To "NOT Display" Products Categorie On Shop Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to not display all the products that have category name is "shoes" in the shop page .

I mean in the shop page display all the products just that have a shoes categorie name and I'll add shoes products in another page exemple (I create a shoes page and will add all the shoes products in it) so please help me (I need that with code php or plugin).

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the codes you've tried so far.

Comment: Corrected spelling errors, formatting and others changes

Answer (score 1):

You could use the woocommerce_product_query hook, which is pretty similar to pre_get_posts except it already has the appropriate conditional logic.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

$tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

$tax_query[] = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( 'samples' ), 
       'operator' => 'NOT IN'
);


$q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );}
```

Comment: You can also check woo commerce docs for this https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy to work, just you need to write one function in your function page.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) { 
if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

$q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array( 'shirt', 'tshirt', 'pant' ), //Category name which      not to want display products on the shop page
'operator' => 'NOT IN'
)));

}

remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Category name(‘shirt’, ‘tshirt’, ‘pant’) which not to want display products on the shop page

Just you can save your page then check,

If you see show any error then you can remove this code from above code lists.

```
remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```